# HackerRank woman codesprint: minimum cost

Tags: java, c#, performance, programming-challenge, linq

> Lauren has a chart of projected prices for a house over the next `n`
>   years, where the price of the house in the `i-th` year is `P_i`. She
>   wants to purchase and resell the house at a minimal loss according to
>   the following rules:
>
> 1. The house cannot be sold at a price greater than or equal to the price it was purchased at (i.e., it must be resold at a loss).
> 2. The house cannot be resold within the same year it was purchased.
>
> Find and print the minimum amount of money Lauren must lose if she
>   buys the house and resells it within the next `n` years.
>
> https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/womens-codesprint-2/challenges/minimum-loss

The minimum cost algorithm is implemented in C++ set, Java TreeSet, no timeout. But, C# code using `SortedSet` has a timeout issue. C# `SortedSet` uses extension methods, using LINQ to simulate TreeSet floor method. I need help with avoiding LINQ performance issues as well as algorithm design, code style, etc.

Java code using `TreeSet`:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numYears = sc.nextInt();
    long[] data = new long[numYears];
    for (int i = 0; i < numYears; i++) {
        data[i] = sc.nextLong();
    }
    TreeSet<Long> values = new TreeSet<>();
    long best = Long.MAX_VALUE;
    for (int i = numYears-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        Long smaller = values.floor(data[i]);
        if (smaller != null) {
            long diff = (data[i] - smaller);
            if (diff >= 0) {
                best = Math.min(best, diff);
            }
        }
        values.add(data[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(best);
}
}
```

C# implementation - failed test cases 11 - 15 due to timeout:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace minimumLoss
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process();
            //Testcase2(); 
        }

        private static void Process()
        {
            int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Int64[] prices = new Int64[n];

            string[] arr = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
            prices = Array.ConvertAll(arr, Int64.Parse);

            Console.WriteLine(MinimumLossCal(n, prices));
        }

        private static void Testcase2()
        {
            Int64[] prices = new Int64[5] { 20, 7, 8, 2, 5 };

            Console.WriteLine(MinimumLossCal(5, prices));
        }

        private static void Testcase3()
        {
            Int64[] prices = new Int64[4] { 2, 3, 4, 1 };

            Console.WriteLine(MinimumLossCal(4, prices));
        }

        /*
         * minimum loss
         *  
         * 
         * read Java TreeSet floor method:
         * https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/treeset_floor.htm
         * 
         * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872946/linq-query-to-select-top-five
         * 
         * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11549580/find-key-with-max-value-from-sorteddictionary
         * 
         * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635497/orderby-descending-in-lambda-expression
         * 
         * timeout issue - try to find LINQ has a solution or not
         * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14675108/sortedset-sortedlist-with-better-linq-performance
         * 
         * 
         */
        private static Int64 MinimumLossCal(int n, Int64[] prices)
        {
            SortedSet<Int64> data = new SortedSet<Int64>();

            Int64 minLoss = Int64.MaxValue;

            for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                var smaller = data.Where(p => p < prices[i]).OrderByDescending(p => p).Take(1);
                if (smaller.Any())
                {
                    Int64 newDiff = prices[i] - smaller.Last();

                    minLoss = (newDiff < minLoss) ? newDiff : minLoss;
                }

                data.Add(prices[i]);
            }

            return minLoss;
        }
    }
}
```

I did study the C# solution to work around the timeout issue - write a binary search tree piggybacked with floor function (similar to Java `TreeSet.floor` functionality), or bucket-sort like solution; see [the blog](http://juliachencoding.blogspot.ca/2016/11/c-sorteddictionary-minimum-cost.html).

Comment: Replace, things like `private static void Testcase3()`with [unit tests](http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/dhananjay_kumar/archive/2015/07/27/getting-started-with-net-unit-testing-using-nunit.aspx)

Comment: @Nathan Cooper, good advice using Nunit test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use GetViewBetween()

I was able to take your `SortedSet` solution and get it to work by using the `GetViewBetween()` method.  The idea is that given a current minimum loss and a new price, you are looking in the set for any price that falls in the range: `price - minLoss + 1` to `price - 1`.  You can use `GetViewBetween()` to find the subset that falls in that range, and take the `Max` of that subset.  This effectively does the same that `floor()` does for a java `TreeSet`.

I compared this solution to the `List + BinarySearch()` solution that you posted in an answer (which you said was your fastest).  On an input of 200000 random values, mine completed in 0.26 seconds compared to 4.8 seconds, for an 18x speedup.

#### Function rewrite

Here is your function rewritten using `GetViewBetween()`:

```
    private static Int64 MinimumLossCal(int n, Int64[] prices)
    {
        SortedSet<Int64> data = new SortedSet<Int64>();

        Int64 minLoss = Int64.MaxValue;

        for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            Int64 curPrice = prices[i];
            Int64 minVal   = curPrice - minLoss + 1;
            Int64 maxVal   = curPrice - 1;
            if (minVal <= maxVal)
            {
                var smaller = data.GetViewBetween(minVal, maxVal);
                if (smaller.Any())
                {
                    minLoss = curPrice - smaller.Max;
                }
            }

            data.Add(curPrice);
        }
        return minLoss;
    }
```

Note that the problem stated that the prices would always be >= 1, which prevents `minVal` from underflowing past `Int64.MinValue`.

Comment: Use SortedSet class GetViewBetween solves the problem perfectly. I have some issues to debug the test case with 200000 random values, the array only holds around 20,000 items after parsing the string. Still try to figure out why. Do you mind sharing your code with the 200000 random values?

Comment: Also, I understood the performance difference between SortedSort:Add and List:Insert. The SortedSort's underneath data structure is binary search tree; but List is a linked list. The time to add a house to the data structure, the first one is O(log(n)), second one is O(n).

Comment: @JianminChen I had the same problem, but I changed my test file to use 32-bit ints and it seemed to work after that.  I think maybe 200000 Int64 values on one line is too many?  I used your code to read the input.

Comment: you also have the issue to do string.Parse(' ') with 200,000 random values? What is your work around?

Comment: thanks for the update. I will think about the reason: Int64 not working, but Int32 is working. 800MB is ok, but it does not work for 1600MB array size.

Comment: @JianminChen Maybe it runs out of memory trying to parse such a large string?  I was thinking to change the input to be one number per line instead of all on one line.  That would make parsing use less memory.

Comment: it should be 1.6MB, not 1600MB for 200,000 random values of Int64.

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite follow your solution.

1. Why do you sort a sorted collection? Either use `OrderBy` with a regular collection, or `SortedSet` without `OrderBy`.
2. Is there any difference between `.OrderByDescending(p => p).Take(1).Last()` and `.Max()`?

   ```
   var smaller = data.Where(p => p < prices[i]);
   if (smaller.Any())
   {
       Int64 newDiff = prices[i] - smaller.Max();
   ```

   Or even `.Last()` instead of `.Max()`, if collection is already sorted?
3. Is there any difference between `n` and `prices.Length`?

All in all, LINQ is a great tool, but not when you have to write a solution to an unrealistic problem that has to meet an unrealistic performance requirement. Use loops instead. The Java code you posted can be easily translated to C# without any major modifications.

If for some reason you need a LINQ solution, this should probably work:

```
private static Int64 MinimumLossCal(Int64[] prices)
{
    return prices
                 //calculate all the differences
                 .SelectMany((currentPrice, i) => prices.Take(i).Select(p => p - currentPrice))
                 //pick only those, that are positive (loss)
                 .Where(difference => difference > 0)
                 //pick minimum
                 .Min();
}
```

But, again, it will never work as fast as a regular loop.

Comment: 1. use SortedSort: need to find a sorting data structure with time complexity O(nlogn), since n is large in the algorithm, O(n^2) sorting will time out, cannot scale;2. LINQ .OrderByDescending(p => p).Take(1).Last() and Max() difference: same idea. The code you wrote in comment 2, I ran it in HackerRank, timeout. 3. n and prices.Length difference: n = prices.Length

Comment: - extra info: I do not want to use LINQ, but SortedSet does not provide API like TreeSet floor API, only thing I learned is to use LINQ. Need C# expert to clarify it on this. The code using your idea: LINQ - SelectMany..., also timeout, here is the code link: gist.github.com/jianminchen/83f0079acbcfc4b6de3f5b1aff6aa131

Comment: @JianminChen, LINQ is designed to create a code that is easy to write and understand. As I said, it *is not* a good choice for competitions and it *will not* give you performance you want. You have to use a combination of regular loops and binary search. `List<T>` has a built-in `BinarySearch` method that you can use to do both: insert elements (too keep the collection sorted) and search for elements (equivalent of `floor` function, if you add `-1` to resulting index).

Comment: excellent advice. It is very easy to try List<T> BinarySearch method, and will see if the performance is good or not. You answered the question of C# algorithm design part as well.

Comment: @JianminChen make sure to read the method's documentation. It returns `The zero-based index of item in the sorted List<T>, if item is found; otherwise, a negative number that is the bitwise complement of the index of the next element that is larger than item or, if there is no larger element, the bitwise complement of Count.`.

Answer (score 0):

With advice from @Nikita B, I did put together a solution using C# List class, and implemented a binary search tree. The time complexity of algorithm is still O(n^2). The C# solution is better than LINQ solution, Test Case #11, #12, #13 still are timeout, but Test Case #14, #15 works fine. Will continue to seek advice and do some research. List Insert API takes O(n) time, since it is a linked list, not a binary search tree.

C# solution can be find through the link here: https://gist.github.com/jianminchen/d6c675533578d50049c636e566695830

Score is 24.50, better than C# SortedSet using LINQ (score 17.50, maximum score 35). 
Here is the function I like to show using List:

```
 /*
     * minimum loss       
     * 
     * read Java TreeSet floor method:
     * https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/treeset_floor.htm
     * 
     * use C# List<T> BinarySearch, Insert API
     * https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4e7fxsh(v=vs.110).aspx
     *      
     * 
     * The idea is to go over each house in the reverse order, add one by 
     * one into the List object, but
     * the List cannot be a binary search tree. 
     * Using BinarySearch to find the position first (Time complexity 
     * O(n)), similar to Java TreeSet class floor method, but Insert 
     * takes O(n) time. 
     * Meanwhile, update minimum loss value if the insertion position 
     * is not the smallest one in the tree. 
     * 
     * Go over each house once, each time, binary search will take 
     * O(logn) time, but Insert takes O(n). Therefore, the final 
     * time complexity should be O(n^2), not O(nlogn). 
     */
    private static Int64 MinimumLossCal(int n, Int64[] prices)
    {
        List<Int64> data = new List<Int64>();

        Int64 minLoss = Int64.MaxValue;

        for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            Int64 curPrice = prices[i];
            var index = data.BinarySearch(curPrice);
            if (index < 0)
            {
                int pos = ~index;
                if (pos > 0)
                {
                    Int64 newDiff = curPrice - data[pos - 1];

                    minLoss = (newDiff < minLoss) ? newDiff : minLoss;
                }

                data.Insert(pos, curPrice);
            }

            // if there is one in the binary search tree, then no need to insert the duplicate one in the tree.                
        }

        return minLoss;
    }
```

Still need to continue to do more research, and get advice.